# Chrome and Firefox Poorly Behaved Under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, cpu-usage

I have a recently-provisioned Lenovo with a 500G SSD drive and 16G of memory. It only has a few things on it and nothing else running, but Chromium will only have a couple of tabs open before it starts blocking on requesting pages.

When I flip over to use Firefox, it will start becoming sluggish or unresponsive with only a couple of windows and tabs. Obviously, this pales in comparison to other environments like Windows or OS X, where I can have dozens of windows open with hundreds of tabs (yes, I realize that I'm probably substituting tabs for love in my life). I've been using Ubuntu for ten years and Linux for twenty.

This is *top*. Notice that the CPU utilization of Firefox is greater than 100%:

[image: ridiculous Firefox utilization]

Comment: I recently noticed simillar issue, but using slightly older (slower) setup. What really helped me was installing [noscript](https://noscript.net/) addon and blocking most of unwanted javascripts. It looks like either javascript engine started to work very slowly in Firefox or somehow number of javascripts on most popular web pages became irrational recently.

Comment: It's a system-level issue. Same browser and same websites don't present the issue on other platforms.

Comment: CPU utilization above 100% often means that the CPU has more than one CPU core and what is shown is actually the SUM of the utilizations of all the cores.  Most programs don't have the capability of using more than one CPU core at a time, though.

Comment: @DustinOprea, did you ever solve this? I thought I did by disabling hardware acceleration in chrome, but turns out nope.

Comment: @komali_2 Nope.

Comment: lol. I think this is the first time I've found something in ubuntu that didn't have a solution buried somewhere int he internet. A genuine "it's broken." What are you doing now? I'm looking up alternatives to compiz + unity.

Comment: I've installed gnome and use that now instead of Unity + Compiz, it's been running quite smoothly.